# How to replace softkeyboard inputconnection text with new text

Tags: android, input, keyboard

I'm creating an app with keyboard translation where input given by keyboard is translated and I wants to replace translated text with input given by user. for this i used following method

```
currentInputConnection.getExtractedText(ExtractedTextRequest(), 0).text = firstTranslation
```

but this method is not working. How can I replace my translated text with original text

Answer (score 0):

```
CharSequence currentText = inputConnection.getExtractedText(new ExtractedTextRequest(), 0).text;
CharSequence before = inputConnection.getTextBeforeCursor(currentText.length(),0);
CharSequence after = inputConnection.getTextAfterCursor(currentText.length(),0);

//Replace code
//inputConnection.setComposingRegion(start of word,end of word);
inputConnection.setComposingRegion(after.length(),before.length());
inputConnection.setComposingText("Translate Text here",currentText.length());
```

In currenttext we get the text that user enter ,
And in Before & After we get the start & end cursor value of currenttext

so now we have to set the range of replace text, how many char u want to replace
that we set in the setcomposingregion() after that we have to set TExt in setComposingtext().

All this code is inside the onkeyUp.

Comment: please add the info on what has to be changed then you can point to example code